# Prestashop - Can I upgrade modules without losing my work?

Tags: prestashop, upgrade, prestashop-modules

I upgraded my version to the latest version 1.7.7.8 and some modules I can't upgrade in back-office only in manual mode ( I buy it from addons ) but this way I lose my work and go back to standard mode.
Does anyone have an idea, please?

Example: I working on this "Registration" page and making some changes

this page origin of Prestashop

[image]

And this the changes

[image]

Note: This is just an example and I found the solution and I mean in other modules when I press upgrade this is what I get and I have it .zip

[image]

When I does the copy and paste I lost my work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes you've made to the registration page have nothing to do with third-party modules.

Uploading the ZIP of an updated module will overwrite only the module in **/modules/{module_name}** folder (and its files).

So uploading an updated version will "start" the upgrade procedure provided by the module developer but nothing else.

I guess for your modification you have acted in the core (or theme / translations) so nothing will be lost with a simple module upload/upgrade.

If I have misunderstood and you have actually made some changes directly on some third-party module files, this is not the "Prestashop" way to work...

There are several ways to override module template in your theme (just put the custom TPL in **/themes/mytheme/modules/xxxx** directory).

Comment: thank you for answer,
But when you need to edit the PHP not in TPL to use Smarty for example or to get value from database what the solution for this?